# How to import multiple table data from SQL Server DB to PostgreSQL DB server through Java code?

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2008-r2, postgresql-9.1, etl

I have around six tables in SQL Server database server and similarly structured tables in a PostgreSQL DB server. What is the best possible approach/idea to import table data from SQL server tables to PostgreSQL server tables through Java code (onclick of a button on JSP page)? Since the tables in SQL Server DB are constantly being modified (INSERTed,UPDATEd & DELETEd), each time the button (to synchronize) is pressed the table data (in all 6 tables) in PostgreSQL server should be deleted and populated again with the latest data from the SQL server tables.

Regards,
Shiva

Comment: Sounds like a slow, bad design that's die a slow, latent death.

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? What's the purpose of having the same thing in two databases and *doing the propagation through a click on a JSP page*?  If you really need the two databases, it should be a background process that does a real backup to an SQL file (via the database manager, not via Java) and loads it in the other database, or something like that.

Comment: I concur: Why?! . If you must do this, you'll want to look at trigger-based replication (where the SQL server DB has triggers to keep a record of changes, and a script connects to that and *replays* the changes onto PostgreSQL), or look into ETL tools that can be scripted to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you all 4 replying, I know this is bad design. But the MS SQL Server DB was designed specifically for another web application. My web application uses PostgreSQL DB server and for just one reporting tool it uses data from those 6 tables in MS SQL server. Do the ETL tools have Java APIs? Can they be called directly in Java code?